# HDMI CEC connections and ground reference

Tags: stm32, ground, hdmi, tv

I'm trying to work with the HDMI-CEC bus and a STM32 microcontroller (currently on a Nucleo-144 board).
I'm connecting a cut HDMI cable with some Dupont wires soldered on it, to interface to the Nucleo. The other side of the cable is plugged in my TV.

From my understanding on the HDMI cable pinout, I should connect the CEC wire (pin 13 of HDMI A type male plug) to the MCU's CEC and the CEC ground (pin 17 of cable) to my Nucleo's ground.
With these connections, I can't read data on the CEC bus and I see on the scope that the line is floating and full of parasites:
[image]

I now tried to connect CEC ground and the cable's shield together, then I have a clean CEC line and valid data readings:
[image]

My question is the following: what is the official/certified way of doing ? I thought that CEC ground was the reference for CEC signals and the shield was not related.

Also, on the +5V wire (pin 18 of plug), I have 3.3V when using the cable's shield as reference. Which device is in charge of supplying the +5V? The TV or the end-device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I have a functional setup:
I connected CEC ground with the cable shield. CEC signal is referenced properly to this ground.
I confirm that +5V has to come from my board and not from the TV according to HDMI spec. It’s referenced to the global ground too.

Comment: That's still because the cable is not made according to HDMI specs so it should not be sold as HDMI cable and you would not have problems with a cable made according to specs.

Answer (score 1):

Likely your cable is poorly made. Very thin cables sometimes lack ground wires. Officially the ground pin should be connected.

The 5V is not from the TV, but it may leak some voltage if you use a multimeter or high impedance oscilloscope.

Comment: The cable is an Amazon basics, so the poorly made cable is a possibility indeed. So you say that merging the grounds is all fine ? And about the +5v, it means that I can supply it from my board ? Thanks !